# Is it possible to update values in MySql without using column names?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi is it possible to update MySql values without specifying column name..

for example

```
update table_name set  name='john',rollnumber='30' where id='5';
```

i want update these `john,30` values without specifying `name,rollnumber`..

is it possible?

Comment: its not possible ....

Comment: So you expect MySQL to guess which value should be updated in each column?

Comment: The main question here is why would you want it to be possible ?

Comment: Using columns by their order instead of by name is a common shortcut newbies tend to want to use, until they shoot themselves in the foot with it. Use column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REPLACE INTO (which works like INSERT INTO) instead of UPDATE but I don't really recommend you to use it. 
The REPLACE INTO method determines if it's an insert or an update, using the primary key value you specified. So you have the risk to insert things in your table. 
Why it's a problem to specify column names ?

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't.

Because, you do not update whole row.

You always update certain columns.

Refer it here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: i want to update all values at every time

Comment: But, MySQL can't guess the column names as it guesses in cases of INSERT.

Comment: okay but somebody says use Replace Query for that.

Comment: one possible solution(if all the values need to be updated), you can drop the row and use insert to insert it again

Comment: But, the ID will be changed, which might affect the existing data.

Comment: yes.Thats what i am also thinking of

Comment: @user3319064 `i want to update all values at every time` could you explain it more clearly ? Are you writing multiple update query ?

Comment: @user3319064 - But you don't update all values every time, your own example shows 3 columns (name, rollnumber and id) but you're only updating 2 of those columns

Comment: yes i update these 2 values everytime

Comment: @user3319064 then writing update query takes less time than writing all other solutions provided here and also any other possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
REPLACE INTO tbl_name (
  PrimaryKey,
  name,
  rollnumber
) VALUES (
  5,
  'john',
  '30'
```

Which is same as

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET name = 'john', rollnumber = '30'
WHERE PrimaryKey = 5;
```